# How do I find min and max elements in an array of Int using closures?

Tags: swift, closures, func

I have a task to make a func with an array and a closure that accepts Int and Int? and returns Bool. Then, I have to find min and max elements of the array using the closure.

Here's what I've done:

```
func task(array: [Int], closure: (Int, Int?) -> Bool) -> Int? {
    var a: Int?  // it's a part of the task - to make an optional variable
    
    for i in array {
        if closure(i, a) {
            a = i
        }
    }
    return a
}


var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 46, 6, 2, 5, 7]
```

But I don't understand how to find min and max using it, what should I put in the closure?

I saw someone did this:

```
let max = task(array: numbers) {
    $1 == nil || $1! > $0
}



let min = task(array: numbers) {
    $1 == nil || $1! < $0
}
```

But I still can't get why did they compare $0 to $1! and why do we need two elements to find one min/max? Can you please explain the logic?

Comment: "why do we need two elements to find one min/max?" How else would you find this, without any comparison of the elements?

Comment: @Sweeper right, but I don't really understand where these two elements came from.
is it that $0 and $1 take numbers from the array and then being compared with one another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task is deliberately a bit strange to teach you about closures, I think. Before fully explaining what is happening, look at this version of the code with different variable names. Try and understand what is happening before reading further.

```
func task(numbers: [Int], compare: (Int, Int?) -> Bool) -> Int? {
    var resultSoFar: Int?  // this is initially nil
    
    for number in numbers {
        if compare(number, resultSoFar) {
            resultSoFar = number
        }
    }
    return resultSoFar
}

let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 46, 6, 2, 5, 7]

let max = task(numbers: numbers) { number, resultSoFar in
    resultSoFar == nil || number > resultSoFar!
}

let min = task(numbers: numbers) { number, resultSoFar in
    resultSoFar == nil || number < resultSoFar!
}

print("min: \(min), max: \(max)")
// "min: Optional(1), max: Optional(46)"
```

The `task` function iterates over each of the numbers and uses the closure to see if each number is a “better” solution than whatever number it had previously found. Since there is no number to start with, `resultSoFar` is initially `nil`. That is why the closure needs to be passed an integer and an optional integer. The first is the candidate number from the array, the second is the best result so far. The `min` and `max` functions need to return `true` if the candidate number is smaller or larger than the number so far so that the final result will be the smallest/largest of all the numbers. If the result so far is `nil` then this is the first candidate number and must be the smallest/largest so far.

Your classmate got their min/max the wrong way round because they are comparing the result so far and the candidate number the wrong way round.

Using force unwrapping (`!`) is best avoided so a slightly better way of using `task` would look like this:

```
let max = task(numbers: numbers) { number, resultSoFar in
    guard let resultSoFar else { return true }
    return number > resultSoFar
}

let min = task(numbers: numbers) { number, resultSoFar in
    guard let resultSoFar else { return true }
    return number < resultSoFar
}

if let min = min, let max = max {
    print("min: \(min), max: \(max)")
} else {
    print("there is no minimum or maximum number in an empty array")
}
```

To “see” the way the task works some debug prints can be added. This should make it really clear how `resultSoFar` is used:

```
func task(numbers: [Int], compare: (Int, Int?) -> Bool) -> Int? {
    var resultSoFar: Int?  // this is initially nil
    
    for number in numbers {
        print("Before checking \(number), resultSoFar is \(resultSoFar)")
        if compare(number, resultSoFar) {
            print("Setting resultSoFar to \(number)")
            resultSoFar = number
        }
    }

    print("Returning \(resultSoFar)")
    return resultSoFar
}
```

When calculating the maximum the debug prints look like this:

```
Before checking 1, resultSoFar is nil
Setting resultSoFar to 1
Before checking 2, resultSoFar is Optional(1)
Setting resultSoFar to 2
Before checking 3, resultSoFar is Optional(2)
Setting resultSoFar to 3
Before checking 46, resultSoFar is Optional(3)
Setting resultSoFar to 46
Before checking 6, resultSoFar is Optional(46)
Before checking 2, resultSoFar is Optional(46)
Before checking 5, resultSoFar is Optional(46)
Before checking 7, resultSoFar is Optional(46)
Returning Optional(46)
```

Comment: you were right, it's clearer with these names, thank you!
did I understand it correctly, that resultSoFar takes the value of each element of the array in turn, like, it overwrites its value, and then compares it with an element of the array?

Comment: `resultSoFar` is used to keep track of the min or max as each of the numbers in the array is tested. This is the “memory” of the method. The method is not directly comparing two elements of the numbers array with each other, it is comparing each element in turn with the best result found so far and, if this number is better, it updates the result so far. By the time all the numbers have been checked (comparing each one in turn with the min’,ax of all the previous elements), resultSoFar will be the smallest/largest of all the numbers.

Comment: I added some more to my answer to show how you can add some debug prints to “see” how the code works.

Answer (score 1):

You already got an excellent explanation and good solutions in [Geoff Hackworth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76005260/1187415). The second argument of the closure is the “best” number found so far, and that is `nil` for the first call of the closure.

For the sake of completeness: One can also use [`Optional.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/map(_:)-7txtz) and optional chaining `??` for this purpose:

```
let max = task(array: numbers) { number, resultSoFar in
    resultSoFar.map { number > $0 } ?? true
}
```

- If `resultSoFar` is `nil` then `true` is returned.
- Otherwise the closure `{ number > $0 }` is called with `$0` being the *unwrapped* value of `resultSoFar` and the result of that comparison is returned.

The `task` function itself can be simplified using `reduce`:

```
func task(array: [Int], closure: (Int, Int?) -> Bool) -> Int? {
    return array.reduce(nil) { closure($1, $0) ? $1 : $0 }
}
```